# how to parse json that contains example @Wordhere

Tags: java, android, json

i hope you are fine.

in usually i parse the simple json String , value , using Hashmap, or ArrayList<Hashmap<String, Object>>.

but this time i find a weird form, for me. and i want to take some idea or guide or help from you.

this for have the same look as Hashmap String , Object, but added a name like @here some word.

this is a picture of what im talking about:

[image]

```
@activity
{"fileName":"main","fileType":0,"keyboardSetting":0,"options":1,"orientation":0,"theme":-1}
{"fileName":"barchart","fileType":0,"keyboardSetting":0,"options":1,"orientation":0,"theme":-1}
@customview
{"fileName":"items","fileType":1,"keyboardSetting":0,"options":0,"orientation":2,"theme":-1}
{"fileName":"dialog_view","fileType":1,"keyboardSetting":0,"options":0,"orientation":2,"theme":-1}
```

when i tried to parse it with the usual way i go error :

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

i hope you help me or guide me, i learn more about that
and thanks in dvance

Comment: That is not JSON text, so it cannot be parsed as-is. That is 4 separate JSON texts, with some extra stuff, so it's up to you to read the `@xxx` lines, and separate the text into 4 pieces. Once you do that, you can parse the 4 individual JSON texts.\

Comment: can you show your code like model class and api calling code

Comment: @Dharmender Manral which code do you mean ? that im using to read json data ?